# Call method on implementation that doesn't exist on interface

Tags: java

There is an interface exported from a library I'm interacting with. For the sake of MCVE, let's say it's an empty interface called `Marker`.

The marker has an implementation of this interface called `MarkerImpl`, which also contains a method called `removeMarker` - but this method isn't on the interface, and `MarkerImpl` **isn't publicly exposed** - I can't import it to cast `marker` to it.

I want to call the `removeMarker` method on my `Marker` instance, so I tried doing this:

```java
interface RemovableMarker extends Marker {
    void removeMarker();
}
```

and then calling it like this:

```java
RemovableMarker removable = (RemovableMarker) marker;
removable.removeMarker();
```

But I get the following error:

> `Marker` cannot be cast to `RemovableMarker`

How can I call `marker.removeMarker`?

Answer (score 1):

By casting it to its **actual** type that has the `removeMarker()` method: `MarkerImpl`.

Java is not structurally typed like TypeScript. If a class doesn't implement an interface, then it doesn't implement it, even if it has a method with the same signature. `MarkerImpl` doesn't implement your interface `RemovableMarker` so an instance of `MarkerImpl` is not a `RemovableMarker`, and cannot be cast to `RemovableMarker`.

Comment: `MarkerImpl` is not distributed, I can't import the type into my project.

Comment: Please see the edit I've just made which highlights this in bold

Comment: Then you shouldn't use that method: the library author chose to not make it public for a reason. And calling it has good chances to break at the next version of the lib, since you would violate encapsulation, and would call a non-public method that could thus disappear.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question. I am aware that I shouldn't use that method, however to implement my requirements, I must call that method

Comment: Use reflection. And then pay the price for months.

Comment: Unfortunately I am having to choose between paying the price for implementing something in a bad way, and paying the price for not implementing it at all - and I regrettably must choose the bad way

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this with `getDeclaredMethod`

```java
Method removeMarker = marker.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("removeMarker");
removeMarker.setAccessible(true);
removeMarker.invoke(marker);
```